# Darboux-Weinstein theorems applied to lagrangian submanifolds that intersect transversally

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I have been reading a symplectic geometry text and at some point they claim the following :

> Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $L_0,L_1$ be two lagrangian submanifolds such that $L_0\pitchfork L_1$. Then in a local situation by Darboux-Weinstein in can consider $M=T^* \mathbb{R}^n$ $\omega=\omega_{can}$, $L_0$ the zero section and $L_1$ to be the graph of $df$ for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $df(0)=0$ and Hess$_0 f>0$.

Now I am not entirely sure why this is possible and would appreciate some help on seeing how one can prove this. By the Weinstein lagrangian neighborhood theorem we can find a neighborhood of $L_0$ such that we can identitfy $M$ with $T^*L$ and $L$ with the zero section. But then applying darboux to $T^*L$ we could lose the zero-section part. Doing darboux first and then Weisntein I am not sure if it works too , and I have no idea how we can see $L_1$ is the graph of $df$ for some $f$ with those conditions.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.